# Write ID3 tags python mutagen

Tags: windows, python-3.x, id3, mutagen

Try to change ID3 tags in mp3 file using python3 & mutagen.
`trackN.add(mutagen.id3.TIT2(encoding=3, text=dict['title']))`
It works on Ubuntu, but on Windows7 all tags are disappear.
No errors in script.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to save the tags in the ID3 second version

```
audio.save(v2_version=3)
```